# Create a box visually in front of background

Tags: html, css, web

I have tried to implement a container like [shown in the picture below](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-QgyjbOTkSo8/U72irZchIJI/AAAAAAAAA7E/QouCN-D8DX4/s1600/neo4j-browser.png) to hold my blog post. White container in the front of background.

[image]

I though if I change background color as white, it will looks like it. But, it did not worked because it seems like both background and mine white boz is same level.

How can I create a box, to hold my blog post, which is looks like in front of background?

(I am developing blog web page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using another div exclusively for the blog posts, so that you can style it easily.

[**This**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jzbsl) should look like the one you want to achieve in a really simpler form.

Sample `HTML` content:

```
<div id="main-container"> <!-- A main container div, for the whole webpage -->
  <h3>Posts</h3>
  <div class="post">
    <h4>Post Title</h4>
    Blog post text here, Blog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text hereBlog post text here
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is how your `CSS` code should look like:

```
#main-container {
  background-color: lightGray;
}

.post {
  margin: 5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px gray; 
}

.post h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

You need to have box shadow, to enable this 3D-like effect. 
I would recommend using multiple-box shadows, you can read more [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/css3-layering-multiple-shadows-creates-lightweight-pages/).

Comment: It seems picture on the question like its totally in front of background color. But, yours seems like border in front of background but white color in it is not. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Hevan I see now, I've updated the CodePen link, and I think this is what you need, take a look, and tell me if you want this or sth different

Comment: I have changed border color as white, it is really what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @Hevan: If you changed it to white, then this means it doesn't show up on the final result (white border on white background), so you could remove the border rule completely. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

To apply "hover" effect, you can use `box-shadow` to visually display element in front of background (by z-index). [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/buveyiluluri/2/edit)

```
#bg {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#fr {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #454545;
  border-radius: 500px
}
```

Comment: @Error404 thx for notifying me that you are answering questions... I have answered too.

Comment: but in the question, picture does not have any shadow.

Answer (score 1):

There may be many designs you can use for this purpose. But I will recommend you to use `border` and `border-radius` properties of inline css. This may lift up your content a little more up. Another inline css property would be `border-style` with which you can define styles like - `dashed`, `solid`, `double`, `groove`, `ridge`, `inset`, `outset`.

It all depends on you which you want to use. If you need an example, just inform me. I hope you understand.

**EDIT**

```
<div class = "" style = "border-radius: 2px; border-style:dashed;">
<!--Text here-->
</div>
```

Comment: examples will help me more. MAy you give a simple one?

Comment: I have edited it. Just see if it suits you.